# Capturing Video in Background using Android Camera2 API

Tags: android, video, background, capture, camera2

I'd like to modify the code of the [Camera2Video-Example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video).

When I leave the application by pressing the Home-Button, it should continue capturing video in Background until I return to the Application and stop the service manually.

Any ideas how to realize this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've got a solution based on [this](https://github.com/chatea/ServiceCamera) example - although it's the deprecated camera api.

Comment: I'm curious, did you ever find out if the same workflow works with the Camera2 API?